How to connect custom storage to django
I am writing a custom storage module to use a remote seafile-server as storage for a django (django-cms) installation.
File seafile.py is located in the project-folder:

The storage class has been tested with jupyter notebook and is working.
The problem: I am failing to connect my storage to django (local, development-server), it is still saving pictures local in the media-folder and not using my storage at all.
In settings.py
from .seafile import MyStorage

...


Things I have tried:
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "MyStorage"
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "seafile.MyStorage"
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = MyStorage
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = MyStorage()

For sure I have seen and tried the suggested solution (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/custom-file-storage/#use-your-custom-storage-engine) but failed too.
What am I missing? Thank you in advance!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#storages

Two changes made the custom storage work:
settings.py
STORAGES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "seafile.seafile.MyStorage",
        "OPTIONS": {...},
    },
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage",
    }
}

Important: Change "seafile.MyStorage" to "seafile.seafile.MyStorage" to reflect "folder.file.class"
